# How to make an monthly dataset using the last day of each month in R dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, dataset, tidyverse

I need to create an new df by using only the last day in each month using R dplyr or maybe tidyverse ...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(BatchGetSymbols)

portfolio <- BatchGetSymbols(
  tickers = c("ZC=F", # Futuros Milho
              "ZO=F", # Futuros Aveia
              "KE=F", # Futuros KC HRW Wheat Futures
              # "ZR=F", # Rough Rice Futures
              "GF=F", # Feeder Cattle Futures
              "ZS=F", # Futuros oleo de soja
              "ZL=F", # Futuros Soja
              "ZM=F"  # Futuros farelo soja
  ),
  first.date = "2019-01-01",
  last.date = Sys.Date(),
  do.cache = FALSE) 

portfolio <- as.data.frame(portfolio$df.tickers) %>%
  select(
    ref.date,
    ticker,
    price.close
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = ticker, 
    values_from = price.close
  )

head(portfolio)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  ref.date   `ZC=F` `ZO=F` `KE=F` `GF=F` `ZS=F` `ZL=F` `ZM=F`
  <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2019-01-02   376.   278.   492.   148.   895.   27.9   311 
2 2019-01-03   380.   278.   504.   147.   900.   28.2   313.
3 2019-01-04   383    280    506    145.   910.   28.4   315.
4 2019-01-07   382.   280.   503    146    912.   28.3   318.
5 2019-01-08   380    283.   505    148.   906.   28.2   318.
6 2019-01-09   382    286.   506.   147.   912.   28.3   319 

glimpse(portfolio)
Rows: 925
Columns: 8
$ ref.date <date> 2019-01-02, 2019-01-03, 2019-01-04, 2019-01-07, 2019-01-08, 2019-01-09, 2019-01-10, 2019-01-11, 2019-01-14, …
$ `ZC=F`   <dbl> 375.75, 379.75, 383.00, 382.25, 380.00, 382.00, 376.25, 378.25, 378.50, 371.25, 374.00, 380.00, 381.75, 379.0…
$ `ZO=F`   <dbl> 278.25, 278.50, 280.00, 279.50, 282.75, 285.75, 288.75, 294.75, 300.00, 292.50, 295.50, 295.75, 298.75, 297.0…
$ `KE=F`   <dbl> 492.50, 503.50, 506.00, 503.00, 505.00, 505.50, 498.75, 504.50, 499.00, 495.50, 495.50, 504.00, 506.00, 509.7…
$ `GF=F`   <dbl> 147.950, 146.525, 144.900, 146.000, 147.625, 146.825, 146.750, 146.125, 144.850, 144.750, 143.775, 141.425, 1…
$ `ZS=F`   <dbl> 894.75, 900.25, 909.50, 912.25, 906.25, 911.50, 895.50, 899.25, 890.75, 893.25, 894.50, 907.75, 916.75, 909.2…
$ `ZL=F`   <dbl> 27.90, 28.18, 28.41, 28.26, 28.18, 28.32, 27.94, 28.17, 28.11, 28.24, 28.23, 28.77, 29.01, 29.06, 29.38, 29.5…
$ `ZM=F`   <dbl> 311.0, 312.7, 315.1, 318.2, 317.6, 319.0, 312.6, 310.4, 306.9, 309.3, 310.1, 312.2, 315.1, 313.0, 312.9, 312.…
```

And then when I trying to use

```
portfolio <- portfolio %>%
  mutate(
    ref.date = ymd(ref.date),
    year_month = floor_date(ref.date, "month"),
    year_month = paste(year(ref.date),"/", formatC(month(year_month, label = FALSE), width = 2, flag = "0")),
    year_month = gsub(" ", "", year_month ),
 #   year_month = as.Date(year_month),
    WeekDay = wday(ref.date, label = TRUE),
    day = day(ref.date)
  )

monthly_dataset <- portfolio %>%
  group_by(year_month) %>%
  filter(day == max(day)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    last_day = ref.date,
    ref.date = yearmonth(ref.date),
    year_month = yearmonth(year_month)
  ) 

monthly_dataset
```

It returns the f* error msg in my RMarkdown file ...

```
Error in max(day) : 'type' invalid (closure) of the argument
```

In normal R script it runs with no issue....but, how can I solve to run this in my RMarkdown file ? Maybe I can change the code ? What is the best way ?

Comment: No need to define day, week, etc. `portfolio %>% group_by(m = floor_date(ref.date, "month")) %>% filter(ref.date == max(ref.date))` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's confusing the function `day` (presumably from lubridate) with the column. You can use the `.data` pronoun to disambiguate.

```
monthly_dataset <- portfolio %>%
  group_by(year_month) %>%
  filter(day == max(.data$day)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    last_day = ref.date,
    ref.date = yearmonth(ref.date),
    year_month = yearmonth(year_month)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcus, but it returned the following error msg: ``Error: ! Can´t subset `.data` outside of a data mask content.``

Comment: Can you rename the column to something that doesn't have a naming conflict (e.g. "day_val")? You could then rename it back to day at the end if you really need to